# How to insert new function without adding inside the self object in JS

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS code, how could I insert new function without adding inside the self object?

```
Function select(selector){
Var self = {
Print: ()=>{},
Delete: ()=>{}
};
Return self;
}
```

//I want to add new function here so I can call it by using select("something").newFunc()

Is there any ways to do that? I tried something as below, but I'm wondering if there's another way to do it.

After several hours of testing, I tried to assign all the methods inside a variable prototype's method (A), and then set A's prototype back to the variable's prototype. Then I can call it using the variable.

```
var myScript = function(selector){
return new myScript.prototype.init(selector);
}
var init = myScript.prototype.init = function(selector){
var self = {
//codes
};
return self;
}
init.prototype = myScript.prototype;
(function(mS){
mS.prototype.newFunc = function(){
return "Coding is Fun";
}
})(myScript);
```

After that, I can use myScript("something").newFunc()

That's what I've tried, please share if you know another way, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructor functions do not require the 'self' object you designed. In your case

1. You return the **self** object from the constructor
2. You use **arrow functions** that do not change the value of **this**. Arrow functions are cool, but they are not interchangeable with regular functions (at least not in every case - and inside a constructor function is such a case)

Look at the two constructor functions below (Select1 is based on your code, Select2 is based on a "how to do it"):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

```js
// adding a self object - arrow functions
function Select1(selector) {
  this.selector = selector
  var self = {
    print: () => {
      return 'Select1 print: ' + this.selector
    },
    delete: () => {
      return 'Select1 delete: ' + this.selector
    }
  }
  return self
}

// no self object - regular functions
function Select2(selector) {
  this.selector = selector
  this.print = function() {
    return 'Select2 print: ' + this.selector
  }
  this.delete = function() {
    return 'Select2 delete: ' + this.selector
  }
  return this
}

// instantiating the two different Objects
let select1 = new Select1('selector1')
let select2 = new Select2('selector2')

// calling the print method on both Objects
console.log(select1.print())
console.log(select2.print())

// logging both objects
console.log(select1)
console.log(select2)

// modifying the prototype of the constructor functions
// modifying Select1.self's prototype would throw an error
/*Select1.prototype.self.newFunc = () => {
  return 'Select1 newFunc: ' + this.selector
}*/
Select1.prototype.newFunc = function() {
  return 'Select1 newFunc: ' + this.selector
}
Select2.prototype.newFunc = function() {
  return 'Select2 newFunc: ' + this.selector
}

// logging the new function

// logging select1.newFunc() would throw an error, as you return 'self', that's not modified
// console.log(select1.newFunc())
console.log(select2.newFunc())

// logging the modified object
console.log(select1)
console.log(select2)
```

**BUT**

- You should use correct indentation - code is much more readable that way
- You should follow naming and casing conventions, so others can quickly see what is what in your code (constructor functions begin with a capital letter, but other reserved words do not (so casing is important too)

**USAGE**

And if you want to use it like `myScript('selector').myFunc()`, then you need to wrap it in another function (like you did in your second code sample):

```js
function Select2(selector) {
  this.selector = selector
  this.print = function() {
    return 'Select2 print: ' + this.selector
  }
  this.delete = function() {
    return 'Select2 delete: ' + this.selector
  }
  return this
}

function myFunc(selector) {
  return new Select2(selector)
}

console.log(myFunc('s1').print())
console.log(myFunc('s2').print())
```

If you want to be able to set the selector, then you need a `set()` function:

```js
function Select2(selector) {
  this.selector = selector
  this.print = function() {
    return 'Select2 print: ' + this.selector
  }
  this.delete = function() {
    return 'Select2 delete: ' + this.selector
  }
  // this.setSelector is the set() function
  this.setSelector = function(s) {
    this.selector = s
  }
  return this
}

function myFunc(selector) {
  return new Select2(selector)
}

// instantiating Select2
const selector2 = myFunc('s1')

console.log(selector2.print()) // expected: s1

// setting the 'selector' of the instantiated
// Select2 Object to a new value
selector2.setSelector('s2')
console.log(selector2.print()) // expected: s2
```